# How to store data with many urls

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I've made a scraping tool which is looking for specifing string in each link's source code. The thing is that I want to store which link contained specific string.
For example:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| String | Links                                  |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| Apple  | example1.com example2.com example3.com |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| Banana | example6 example1 example12124         |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| Carrot |                                        |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| Melon  | example2                               |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

It would be nicer to me to have static stings instead of Links. Thats becase I am adding new links to scraper every day, but the strings stays the same.

Of course I could store full links in every row, but that is horrible solution. Can you tell me what should I do? I was thinking about tranforming each link to unique code for example from:

`example.com`
to:
`m!93xp`

It takes less space, but still I think that is not a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: You definitely do NOT want to store delimited data. That is in violation of 1NF. You might add an identity to your String table and then have that StringID be the primary key and also a foreign key in your Links table.

Comment: You should store the links in their own table and have a one to many relationship from key strings to links. I think it's okay to store the entire link then, unless you really need to save space because you have too many.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a couple of times to read to understand what your issue is/was and what you are really asking.  A normalized structure would yield 3 tables in a many to many relationship.

- Links Table that stores the full link to an auto generated primary key
- Strings Table that stores the string to an auto generated primary key
- Occurrences Table that stores the LinkId an StringId and an auto generated primary key.

This would be the least repetitive data and likely the least cost on disk space because you won't be repeating the string or the links if they are long but rather a 4 or 8 byte integer.  Note almost all modern databse servers have methods to handle and auto generate a numeric key you should let them do it and not try to generate your own unique code!

Something like this:

```
create table Strings
(
    StringID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , StringValue VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

create table Links
(
    LinkID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Occurences
(
    OccurenceId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,StringId INT NOT NULL
    ,LinkId INT NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: I would have to assign about 3000 from 15000 different strings to 10000 different urls. That is a big about of `occurance` rows. Local database would handle that?

Comment: so 3 million records that's not so big but it will depend on your system.  But think of it this way.  if you replicate those 10,000 urls 3,000 times how many it is still 3 million occurrences but now it is a long lets so 100-200 character string which will take up at least 200 bytes per occurrence  my way takes up 12 bytes per occurrence......

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sketch of what I would suggest. I did not explicitly define any primary or foreign keys in this. It is late Friday afternoon and I am ready for beer. :)

```
create table Strings
(
    StringID int identity
    , StringValue varchar(100)
)

create table Links
(
    LinkID int identity
    , StringID int not null
    , URL varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: It is likely that a link could have more than 1 of the strings in it so I would actually recommend a many to many relationship as the link itself is probably the highest data cost

Comment: I didn't initially see this as a many to many but reading it again I believe you may be correct.